# Normal Equation in Python Improvement needed

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am new to Python and would like to code myself for the normal equation. The code is following, please provide some suggestions and feedback on coding. Thank you!

```
def norm_equ(x, y):
    x_input = pd.DataFrame(x)
    x_input = (x_input - x_input.mean())/x_input.std()
    x_0 = np.ones((len(x_input), 1))
    x_new = np.hstack((x_0, x_input))
    temp1 = np.linalg.pinv(np.dot(np.transpose(x_new), x_new))
    temp2 = np.dot(temp1, np.transpose(x_new))
    theta = np.dot(temp2, y)
    return theta
```

My question is about: how to add $ X_0 $ in the data? Is there any other way to work than the data.frame data structure? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: pandas library relies heavily on NumPy implementations. if your main concern is efficiency it worth taking a look into np.ndarray

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I am switching from R to Python and that is why I work on data frame to work this out. I think array or ndarray would be a better choice. BTW, my most concern is how to obtain the # of columns? I can use len(an_array) to obtain the # of rows, but I don't think it would work when I just take one column out of the data frame, since it would become a series. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I putting some examples of how to use numpy, hopefully it will answer your questions. In general, for numerical operations go for numpy and for more generic operations ( strings, aggregating etc) go for pandas. In general pandas is good for preparing the data and pass it to a more lower level data structure such as numpy to heavier calculations

you asked
1) which data structure to use ? go for multidimensional arrays in numpy

2) how to obtain the # of columns? for a np.array you just need to use .shape, it it's a tuple of (dim1, dim2 .... ) usually (n_rows, cols)

3) is a np.array of  1 dimension, that's why you have shape like this (n_rows, ) so if you print y you will see a vector ... so you only have one column. np.arrays can be confusing in the beginning because the allow you to create things more generic than vector or matrices such as tensors wich would be a np.array of shape (x, y, z). So it makes sense talking about columns for np.arrays of of shape (n_rows, n_cols)

4) if the column std() is 0, all the instances are the same, so basically there's no point applying this normalization to the column of ones. (just skip it)

In more detail, Usually the goal of standardising your columns is to make the values in that columns fall in a range of values. I.e. between 0 and 1. This is done in machine learning for example to avoid that a column(feature) of your training data that has biggers values would affect more the model than other with smaller values. You can notice that the normalization you're applying don't force the columns to be in [0, 1]. so a normalization that would force that and wouldn't give division error like the other normalization (unless max and min = 0) would be:

```
x_raw = (x_raw - x_raw.min())/(x_raw.max() - x_raw.min())
print(x_raw)
```

```
import numpy as np
def norm_equ(x, y):
    temp1 = np.linalg.pinv(np.dot(np.transpose(x), x))
    temp2 = np.dot(temp1, np.transpose(x))
    theta = np.dot(temp2, y)
    return theta

# create a matrix 50x10 random matrix
x_raw = np.random.random([50,10])
y = np.random.random([50])
print(x_raw.shape) #-----> (50, 10)
print(y.shape) #-----> (50, ) a vec "50 x 1"

# transform raw input
x_norm = (x_raw - x_raw.mean())/x_raw.std()
x_0 = np.ones((x_norm.shape[0],1))
x_input = np.hstack((x_0, x_norm))
print(x_input.shape) #-----> (51, 11)
theta = norm_equ(x_input, y)
print(theta.shape) #-----> (11, ) 

# load from csv file
arrays_from_file = np.loadtxt(fname="dummy.csv",
                              delimiter=",",
                              skiprows=1)
y = np.random.random([arrays_from_file.shape[0]])
print(arrays_from_file.shape) #-----> (2, 6)
print(y.shape) #-----> (2, )
another_theta = norm_equ(arrays_from_file, y)
print(another_theta.shape) #-----> (6, )
```

Comment: Thank you, @bernardo-stearns-reisen. I will use the arrays for the data multiplication in next assignment. I would like to check two more thins in your codes. 1. y supposes to be a series. Then how should we judge its # of columns, which is None here. 2. For ``X``, the first column is full of 1, then how should we standardize it? I mean if the the original data contains the X_0 = 1? It would produces error in ``/x.std()``. Appreciate.

Comment: @Bernardo-steams-reisen. Thank you for your clarification. It helps a lot. I think most of my question now is about the data structure, like dictionary, list, array, and tuple. I am a little bit comfortable for data frame and sframe since they also exist in R. I think I would work more on this part first.

Comment: I'm glad it benefited you, if you're happy with the answer please accept the answer as correct :)

Comment: Thank you for your help. Once I completed my next program, I will post it and hopefully you will provide me some suggestions on it.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you converting x to a DataFrame? Seems like it should just be a numpy array given the rest of the code.

If you want a dataframe with three columns, then it would be

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x_input': x, 'x_0': 1})
df['x_input_norm'] = df['x_input'] - df['x_input'].mean() / df['x_input'].std()
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I am switching from R to Python and that is why I work on data frame to work this out. I am not sure which format of data structure I should use here. My another concern is how to obtain the # of columns? I can use len(an_array) to obtain the # of rows, but I don't think it would work when I just take one column out of the data frame, since it would become a series. Thank you.

Comment: ```len(df.columns)``` gives you the number of columns. You can also use the ```shape``` property of the dataframe, which returns a tuple of (number_of_rows, number_of_columns).

Comment: Thank you, @Eric Truett. I dont't think they are functional well for pandas series, e.g. data['y']. If you take a column out of the data frame, the pandas will record it as a series. And data.columns and shape wont't work.